# React - TypeError: _this.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am playing with React and trying to save the text that user type to the input to the `state`. I have added to the textarea an `onChange` attribute for setting the state.

However, when I start typing, I see error in the console stating `TypeError: _this.setState is not a function`.

I've tried different ways of trying to fix it, but still don't have it.

```
const NewItemForm = props => (
    <Form onSubmit={props.send_form}>
        <Form.Group>
            <TextArea 
                placeholder='Name your first item here' 
                name='item_msg'
                onChange={e => this.setState({ item_msg: e.target.value })} />
            <Form.Button primary content='Create Item' />
        </Form.Group>
    </Form>
)

class App extends Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
          item_msg: ''
        }
    }

    handleSubmit(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(this.state.item_msg);  
    }  

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <MainHeaderr />
                <Container>
                    <NewItemForm send_form={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} />
                </Container>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Functional components are stateless so you can't call `setState` within them

Comment: Either put `const NewItemForm = props => (` into the App classes constructor or you cant use this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functional components do not have lifecycle methods and... `state` :)

```
const NewItemForm = props => (
    <Form onSubmit={props.send_form}>
        <Form.Group>
            <TextArea 
                placeholder='Name your first item here' 
                name='item_msg'
                onChange={e => this.setState({ item_msg: e.target.value })} />
            <Form.Button primary content='Create Item' />
        </Form.Group>
    </Form>
)
```

This won't work:

```
onChange={e => this.setState({ item_msg: e.target.value })} />
```

What you need is to pass callback:

```
const NewItemForm = props => (
    <Form onSubmit={props.send_form}>
        <Form.Group>
            <TextArea 
                placeholder='Name your first item here' 
                name='item_msg'
                onChange={props.onInputChange} />
            <Form.Button primary content='Create Item' />
        </Form.Group>
    </Form>
)

class App extends Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
          item_msg: ''
        }

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.item_msg);  
    }  
    handleInputChange(e) {
        this.setState({ item_msg: e.target.value })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <MainHeaderr />
                <Container>
                    <NewItemForm send_form={this.handleSubmit} onInputChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                </Container>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I get where you are coming from, but `NewItemForm` will get transpiled to React Element so `this` will reference that Element, not the `App` component.

[React without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html)

Comment: Hi @Tomasz, thank you for your post. I am trying to modify it according to your code, but still seeing `Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function at Object.handleInputChange [as onChange]`. I am must be overlooking something

Comment: @user984621 then I'm pretty sure you need to bind these functions. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, it works! May I ask you, please, what's the rule of thumb when to bind a function? It seems to be a bit like a black box here

Comment: Whnever you use ‚this’ keyword. I personally use Babel transform-class-properties to avoid explicit binding e.g ‘handleSubmit = e => { this.setState...’

Answer (score 3):

Functional components are stateless so you can't call `setState` within them. You can pass a callback from your parent component that sets state in the parent component as follows:

```
handleChange = e => this.setState({ item_msg: e.target.value });

<NewItemForm onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

And then in your `NewItemForm` component:

```
<TextArea 
  placeholder='Name your first item here' 
  name='item_msg'
  onChange={props.onChange} 
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

NewItemForm is function component and function comopent does not have lifecycle method use class component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use arrow function or bind the function in constructor like below

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { date: new Date() };
this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
}
setInterval(()=>this.tick, 1000);
```

or Use arrow function

```
setInterval(()=>this.setState({
    date: new Date(),
  }), 1000);
```